# ToolStripControlHost selection on mouseover

Tags: winforms, hover, selection, mouseover, toolstripcontrolhost

I have a problem developing a custom menu item.

The menu item is hosted in a `ToolStripControlHost`, the rest are just `ToolStripMenuItems`.

What I want is that when the user hovers the mouse over the custom control, to be selected like an ordinary `ToolStripMenuItem`, like in the image below. Unfortunately, I did not manage to figure this out. Is this behavior possible?

[image: screenshot]

Edit: 26.10.2015:
I have been playing around with the control and it seems that the ToolStripControlHost, when added to the ContextMenu it is shrinked in the list, like in the image below.

I made the background of the custom control red so it can be seen better. The control only receives MouseHover events only when the mouse is over the control, shown in red. If you point the mouse on the left or the right, the ContextMenu receives the events.

[ContextMenu custom menuitem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghRdN.png)

It is an interesting behaviour, because also the ToolStripTextBox or ToolStripCombobox don't take the whole left to right space and are not highlighted when mouse is over.
Now I hope someone has an idea how to do that.